# Equivalence of expectation condition for contingent claims attainable and contingent claims super replicable

Tags: options, stochastic-processes, finance, finance-mathematics, arbitrage

We have the following definitions for set of contingent claims attainable and contingent claims super replicable
[image]

[image]

I want to prove the following result

[image]

How do I show iii $\implies $ ii.I understand that it is trivial that $\mathbb E[f]\leq 0$.But how do I show the other inequality?